# Is there a way to automate nuget install/update?

Tags: c#, automation, nuget

One of the tasks of my program would be updating/installing nuget packages (and properly managing projects which are updated). So I wonder -- is there a way to automate already existing software to do this. If yes -- how?

**Example**: let' say I have project "A" which already has package "B" 1.0 and "C" 1.0 installed. There are newer version for both, and I would like to update only "B", but not "C".

Nuget CLI is out of the question for now, because its update is limited (it updates **all** packages), but worse, both install/update commands do not manage properly the projects (required references are not added).

On the other hand VS nuget package manager can everything, but it lives within VS and secondly I need to automate install/update, not rely on manual work.

Comment: Yes there is, I have an web project that updates itself using nuget. I took as base project this one: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx/

Comment: @Boanerge, thank you very much, I will have to digest it for a while to check if the project being updated is properly maintained (see: http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html). This is crucial, because fetching newer version is just part of the equation :-)